# Spring Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I can successful build my code via ./gradlew build -x test, however, when I start my application, it shows

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

below is the dependency of my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    ext {
        projectVersion = '1.3.0-RELEASE'
        grpcVersion = '1.6.1'
        protobufVersion = '3.3.0'
        protobufGradlePluginVersion = '0.8.0'
        springCloudConsulVersion = '1.2.1.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.liferay:gradle-plugins-node:4.3.0"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

dependencies {       
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"){
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:${springCloudConsulVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '3.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.1.Final')
}
```

I think it might be a issue with those version, but Im not sure. In the other hand, most solution I found was marven, the starting of my application is like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, Im using Oracle JDK 1.8

Comment: *"when I start my application"* How are you starting the application? It seems like a classpath problem, but to confirm and for how to fix, we need to know how you're currently doing it.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for mention. I just edited with the way I start the spring application

Comment: I don't see how you're starting the application. I see more Java source code, but that doesn't run unless you execute some command on a command-line, or use an IDE, or something like that. If the issue is that you're missing a jar file from the classpath, showing us a source file is of no use.

Comment: @Andreas I start via termial via java -jar build/libs/Main.jar

Comment: These errors come from mixing incompatible versions of parts of the framework. You use Spring Boot 2.0 and an older Spring Cloud 1.2. Next you also use elasticsearch by a manual dependency, instead use the elasticsearch starter from Spring Boot to have proper dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Cloud 1.2 which is bound to Spring Boot 1.5. You have defined to use Spring Boot 2.0 hence incompatible versions of jars of the same framework.

Next you are also manually including the elasticsearch dependency instead of using the Spring Boot provided starter, probably again another incompatible version of Spring is being pulled in.

In short your dependencies are a mess. Use the proper Spring Cloud version for the selected Spring Boot version or vice version. So either upgrade the Spring Cloud version to a 2.x version or lower the Spring Boot version you are using.

Finally add the `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` instead of the `spring-data-elasticsearch` dependency to have a properly managed version.